# Android Studio SDK JUnit tests not working

Tags: android, junit, sdk

I'm fairly new to android studio and I'm trying to do some JUnit tests on an app that I'm making. But I keep getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebug'.
> Test filtering is not supported for given version of JUnit. Please upgrade JUnit version to at least 4.6.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 11.791 secs
Test filtering is not supported for given version of JUnit. Please upgrade JUnit version to at least 4.6.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to give us more detail to be able to fix it

Comment: So... why not do what it suggests and *"(...) run with --stacktrace or --info or --debug (...)"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps-

1. Go to Menu RUN-> Run Configuration
2. And Add the Test Runner as per below screenshot
3. Run with "MyTest" runner
   [image]